# Задать формулу циклом

Tags: c++

Есть формула:

[image]

Нужно задать ее в виде цикла, желательно без использования pow.

Знаю, как записать ее в общем виде, но в цикл никак не получается затолкнуть, так, чтобы можно было задать n слагаемых.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    float summa = 0;
    double res = 0;

    cout << "Enter n: ";
    cin >> n;

    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
    {
        res = log(x + sqrt(x*x+1));
        summa = summa + res;
    }

    cout << "Result: " << summa << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Так (в инклуды добавить `<math.h>`)?

Comment: Нужно задать то, что после равно записано (а в ходе задачи потом сравнивать с логарифмом)

Т.е. Я ввожу Х= 1 и N=1, на выводе получаю 1, так как первый член последовательности x, ввожу N=2, получаю результат этого выражения: x-1/2*x^3/3 и так далее.